# Sequelize Typescript create object with associations

Tags: node.js, typescript, sequelize.js, sequelize-typescript

I'm trying to build a new instance with OneToOne association, according to https://www.npmjs.com/package/sequelize-typescript

models/measure.ts :

```
@Table({ tableName: "measure" })
export class Measure extends Model {
    ...

    // Token
    @ForeignKey(() => Token)
    @Column({ type: DataType.INTEGER, allowNull: false, unique: true })
    id_token!: number

    @BelongsTo(() => Token)
    token!: Token
}
```

models/token.ts :

```
@Table({ tableName: "token" })
export class Token extends Model {
    ...

    // Measure
    @HasOne(() => Measure)
    measure: Measure
}
```

my sequelize instance :

```
export const sequelize: Sequelize = new Sequelize({
    ...
    repositoryMode: true,
})
sequelize.addModels([Token, Measure])

export const tokenRepository = sequelize.getRepository(Token)
export const measureRepository = sequelize.getRepository(Measure)
```

now i want to create a new Measure instance, with an existing Token :

```
const token = await tokenRepository.findOne({where: {value: value}})
...
console.log(token.isNewRecord) // false
const measure = measureRepository.build({...params, token: token}, {include: [{model: tokenRepository}]})
console.log(measure.token.isNewRecord) // true

await measure.save() // it try to insert an new token here
```

Sequelize try to insert a new token instead of insert only the measure. Where is my mistake ?

Answer (score 0):

I faced this issue some times ago and by reading the docs and trying few things on my side I conclude it was not possible.

From what I saw you can create a new object and all is nested objects in one time. But you can't create a new object and link it to other existing objects in one time.

To do so you will have to do yourself the necessary find and/or update.

I never managed to make it work in one step and the documentation never talk about this. Always says that all elements are new.

> An instance can be created with nested association in one step, provided all elements are new.

For more details :
https://sequelize.org/master/manual/creating-with-associations.html